# IValidatableObject is useless for EF navigation properties?

Tags: .net, validation, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

IValidatableObject.Validate only gets called when the implementing entities DbEntityEntry.State differs from "Unchanged". And just changing a navigation property won't change the state and so the validation will never occur.

Why Microsoft always releases half-baked beta things?

I cannot even detect the navigation property change by hand:

```
var changes = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
    .ToArray();
```

Returns an empty array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few interesting points here. EntityFramework tracks changes to navigation properties independently on the changes to entities. context.ChangeTracker.Entries() returns only changes to entities and not to relationships. This is the reason why you don't see these. If you really want to look at relationships and how they changed you can drop down to the ObjectContext and do the following:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) ctx).ObjectContext;
foreach(var relationshipEntry in objectContext.ObjectStateManager
                                              .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted)
                                              .Where(e => e.IsRelationship))
{
    EntityKey entityKey1, entityKey2;

    if (relationshipEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        entityKey1 = (EntityKey)relationshipEntry.CurrentValues[0];
        entityKey2 = (EntityKey)relationshipEntry.CurrentValues[1];            
    }
    else
    {
        entityKey1 = (EntityKey)relationshipEntry.OriginalValues[0];
        entityKey2 = (EntityKey)relationshipEntry.OriginalValues[1];                        
    }

    var entity1 = objectContext.GetObjectByKey((EntityKey)entityKey1);
    var entity2 = objectContext.GetObjectByKey((EntityKey)entityKey2);
}
```

The scenario that is more interesting to me is the one when you need to re-validate your entity when the relationship changes. I assume that you don't have foreign keys - otherwise your entity would have been marked as modified as changing the navigation proprerty would change the value of the foreign key which in turn would mark the entity as modified. Anyways given that I have three valid entities - what is the scenario where changing relationships could make the entity (or the model) invalid? Also, note that validation by itself is only validating the given entity but never follows navigation properties to validate related entities.
Finally if you really need to validate entities when relationships change I think you have 4 options:

- try adding foreign keys so that changing relationships will change the foreign key which should mark the entity as modified (disclaimer: I have not tried that)
- override DbContext.ShouldValidateEntity() method to validate all the entities instead of only modified ones (this is where the filtering logic happens). Note that it may have some negative impact on performance. Here is the code you would need to add to your class derived from DbContext:

```
        protected  override bool ShouldValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry)
        {
            return (entityEntry.State & EntityState.Deleted) == 0;
        }
```

- override DbContext.SaveChanges() so that you invoke validation for all modified entities and for all entities that are involved in modified relationships (use the code above, you are most likely only interested in relationship entries that have been added)
- when you modify a collection manually mark the entity as modified. Note that it may cause sending unneeded updates to the database so depending on how many entities you are tracking it may be much cheaper just to validate all but deleted entities

You can find more details about validation and validation customization here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/15/ef-feature-ctp5-validation.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/27/ef-4-1-validation.aspx
(Yes it's for the CTP and EF 4.1 but it sill holds)

Comment: What if I have a many relationship? I have a business-/object-rule which says: If the boolean property A is true then collection B is not allowed to be empty. Isn't this part of object-level validation? Should I do this at a different place?

Comment: BTW: Now that it have added foreign keys, the ObjectStateManager does not return any relationship entries any more (the entity itself, more precisely the foreign key properties are now marked as changed, just as you expected)

Comment: 1-* is a very interesting scenario in this context. The reason for this is that adding and removing entities to the collection will not actually have any impact on the entity on the '1' side (i.e. the principal) - if you look at the database the corresponding table will not have foreign keys for the related entities so it does not even know that they exist. In the related table however there will be rows added (or removed) that will have a foreign key pointing to the principal (but not other way around). So was the principal really modified if none of the values were modified?

Comment: I added one more option to the list you may want to consider. In general I think in your case the easiest thing in your case will be to validate all the entities regardless of the state (OK. you don't need to validate Deleted ones) - I updated the response with a code snippet that shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanx. I'm aware that there is no change to the principal "entity" at the DB level. But since I'm working with POCO "entities" my validation targets these objects. So I decided to override ShouldValidateEntity but also added a property ForceValidation to the context: `return this.ForceValidation
    ? ( entityEntry.State & EntityState.Deleted ) == 0
    : base.ShouldValidateEntity(entityEntry);` ; this way it only happens when needed and all related entites are really loaded (LazyLoading is disabled most of the time).

Comment: Seems like a very reasonable solution to me.