# How to track changes of collections

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a class that contains objects of another class:

```
public class Container
{
    public BindingList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    ...
}
```

Objects of the `Container` are attached to a `DbContext`. I want to override the `DbContext's` `SaveChanges()` to send all changes via a WCF service.

Primitive attributes are no problem. They are reflected in the `Entries`. But if the relationship between an `Item` and its `Container` changes (e.g. a new item is added or an existing item is deleted) there is no entry about that in the ChangeTracker.

I could add a `ForeignKey` in the Item class to force a `Modified` entry, but this does not help me much, because I need to know the containing object.

I also tried to convert the `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` to get all related items of an entity. But I see no way to get the actual object of a `RelatedEnd`.

Is there a way to track changes of the contained collection?

### Update

As requested, some code I already have:

```
//In a DbContext subclass
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    //get all modified entities
    var changes = this.ChangeTracker.Entries();
    foreach (var c in changes)
    {
        //check the state of the entity
        switch (c.State)
        {
            //send according WCF callback to the clients
            case System.Data.EntityState.Added:
                App.Current.ServerManager.SendEvent(s => s.EntityAdded((IIdentifiable)c.Entity), causedBy);
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

With this code, I cannot detect changes of the `Items` collection.

Comment: sounds like you're trying to build an audit trail? it'd be helpful if there were more words about the design, less words about code and more code.

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with audit trails. I just want the client to be up to date. Therefore, I want to notify it, when relevant data changes. And to achieve this task I have to detect, IF and WHAT relevant data changes.

Comment: Have you considered event sourcing? http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/20/why-use-event-sourcing/

Comment: @Jeff Vanzella: It seems, this is a similar approach as Abe Miessler suggested below. Therefore, it is not really applicable. Correct me, if I'm wrong. Entity framework must have the functionality I am looking for. I just don't know, how to access it.

Comment: Looks similar.  That is why I put it as a comment, not an Answer

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300156/ivalidatableobject-is-useless-for-ef-navigation-properties/10304323#10304323 it shows how to get added relationships. Hopefuly it will help you get what you need.

Comment: @Pawel: Thanks, that works great. Please add this as an answer, so I can grant you the bounty.

Comment: Not sure if you tried ObservableCollection<T> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: @ElvisLives: `ObservableCollection<T>` is not an option either. I used a `BindingList<T>` which is somewhat similar to an `ObservableCollection<T>` in terms of change notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300156/ivalidatableobject-is-useless-for-ef-navigation-properties/10304323#10304323) it shows how to get added relationships. Hopefuly it will help you get what you need.